# Put some text in the bottom of the title page with amsbook

Tags: positioning, titles, amsbook

I'm using amsbook to write my thesis, while it's required to put some information in the bottom in the title page.

Here is my direct trial:

```
\documentclass[12pt, final]{amsbook} 
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{T}
\author{\large \textbf{by\\Oslo}\\
    \vfill
    Some Info.
    }
\date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

It then looks like:

[image]

The "Info" is quite far from the bottom. Hence I would like to ask how I can put the text to the bottom.

Comment: Since you are adding your info in the `\author` field, you could change the `\vfill` to an explicit `\vspace{...}`, specifying a dimension value that will move the info down to the desired position.  This is, admittedly, a hack, but I am assuming that the author data won't be used automatically for anything else.  (At the AMS, the `\author{...}` isn't used for anything else, and this title page is used solely for identifying the file that is in production.  Other users may have different ideas.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are looking for title page footnote, please refer the below tags:

```
\documentclass[12pt, final]{amsbook} 
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\let\thefootnote\relax

\title{T\footnotetext{This is footer of the opening page}}
\author{\large \textbf{by\\Oslo}}
\date{}

\maketitle

\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[12pt, final]{amsbook} 
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\let\thefootnote\relax

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule

\let\footnoterule\relax

\title{T\footnotetext{This is footer of the opening page}}
\author{\large \textbf{by\\Oslo}}
\date{}

\maketitle

\newpage

\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
\let\footnoterule\oldfootnoterule

Test\footnote{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very close to what I want, but is it possible to take the line segment off? And not that left and bottom, e.g. move it 0.5inch up and right?

Comment: It's possible with some manual work, `\title{T\footnotetext{This is footer of the opening page\vspace*{6pc}}}` will help you to move the text up or down...

Comment: Thanks! But I still hope that I can move it a bit to the left and make it without the line segment.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the rule above the footnote?

Comment: Yes! Is it easy to get rid of this?

Comment: @Salomo Please check the edited answer...